# Django key, value dictionary returning data under the same key

Tags: python, django, firebase

I'm pulling post data from my firebase database and trying to pass it into my template in Django. I can easily pass just the values into the template but I'm trying to also pass the ID using a key-value dictionary but for some reason, I can't get it to work the way I want it to. It's returning all the values under the same key I would like each key to match the relating value.

**Database structure:**

```
"posts" : {
"-LqytRym_35j-6il-nHQ" : {
  "title" : "Purple",
  "uid" : "LTAeaDscQyexbud3ijIMYpDCucO2"
},
```

**Views.py:**

```
posts = database.child("posts").child(favKey).get()

posts_dict.append(posts.val())

at1 = {posts.query_key:[posts.val()]}

print(at1)

return render(request, 'users/favourites.html', {'posts': at1})
```

**Template:**

```
{% for key, value in posts.items %}
<article class="media content-section col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
  <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ key }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ value.title }}</a></h2>
    <p class="article-content">{{ post.uid }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it is not clear that, in what structure you need the output

Comment: What does it print for ```print(at1)```?

Answer (score 1):

`at1 = {posts.query_key:[posts.val()]}` will result in a dict with only **one** entry.

The entry has the key `posts.query_key` (which is not the same as `posts.query_key()` btw, think about what you want) and the the value `[posts.val()]` (which is a single object: a list).

You can use dict comprehension instead:

```py
at1 = {post.query_key : post.val() for post in posts}
```

This will give you an entry for every element in posts.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm getting this error when trying to run the code you posted. `'PyreResponse' object is not iterable`. It goes away when I remove `for post in posts` but only 1 post is then returned.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what a PyreResponse object is. But it seems from the [Readme](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) that you might have to replace `posts` with either `posts.each()` or `posts.val()` (which seems to return an iterable version of posts). Could you if one of those works for you?

Comment: I get the error `'NoneType' object is not iterable` when trying both `for post in posts.each()` and `for post in posts.val()` which i think means the data is none but the posts.val() returns objects when I print it out